# Does super try each class in MRO

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, super

```
class Base(object):
    def m(self):
        print 'base'


class MixinA(Base):
    def m(self):
        super(MixinA, self).m()
        print 'mixin a'


class MixinB(Base):
    def m(self):
        super(MixinB, self).m()
        print 'mixin b'


class Top(MixinB, MixinA, Base):
    def m(self):
        super(Top, self).m()
        print 'top'


t = Top()
t.m()
```

This prints:

```
base
mixin a
mixin b
top
```

I'm surprised by multiple things. First MRO of `Top` is `(<class 'Top'>, <class 'MixinB'>, <class 'MixinA'>, <class 'Base'>, <type 'object'>)`

1. Why `mixin a` comes before `mixin b`?
2. Does `super` try every class in MRO (unlike searching for an attribute when the first attribute found is returned)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `super()` does not 'try' each class in the MRO. Your code **chains** the calls, because each method called has **another** `super()` call in it. `Top.m()` calls `super().m()`, which resolves to `MixinB.m()`; which in turn uses `super()` again, etc.

`mixin a` is printed before `mixin b` because you are printing **after** the `super()` call, so the *last* element in the MRO is executed first. The `super()` call is *just another method call*, so a `print` statement after such a call won't be executed until the `super().m()` call has completed.

Your MRO is as follows:

```
>>> type(t).__mro__
(<class '__main__.Top'>, <class '__main__.MixinB'>, <class '__main__.MixinA'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <type 'object'>)
```

so naturally `Base.m()` is called last and gets to print first, followed by `MixinA`, then `MixinB`, and `Top` being the last to print.

Note that the MRO of `self` is used, not of the class you pass into `super()` as the first argument; the MRO is thus stable throughout all calls in your hierarchy for any given instance.

If you expected the print statements to be executed in the order the MRO calls are chained, you'll have to put the `print` statements *before* calling the next `m()` method in the MRO.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *trying* involved, here: Your call order is

- `Top.m()` calling `super(Top, self).m()` which is `MixinB.m()`.
- `MixinB.m()` immediately calls `super(MixinB, self).m()` which is `MixinA.m()` when called with `type(self) == Top`. `super()` uses the MRO of the `self` object, hence we need to look at `Top`, not at the standalone `MixinB`.
- `MixinA.m()` calls `super(MixinA, self).m()` which is `Base.m()`.

There are no more super calls at that point, so

- `Base` does the `print 'base'` and returns (to `MixinA.m()`)
- `MixinA.m()` prints `'mixin a'` and returns (to `MixinB.m()`)
- `MixinB.m()` prints `'mixin b'` and returns (to `Top.m()`).
- `Top.m()` prints `'top'` and returns to the caller.

The prints are in reverse call order because you are executing them after the super call chain.

Comment: `super(MixinB).m()` does not call `MixinA.m()`

Comment: @Marii: yes, it does. `MixinA` is the next class in the MRO of `type(self)`.

Comment: @Marii: Don't get confused. We use the MRO of `Top` not that of `MixinB` as a standalone class. When mixed into `Top` as shown, `super(MixinB, self)` (with `type(self) == Top`) is actually `MixinA`.